# SELECT, WHERE MYSQL php table confusion

Tags: php, mysql

[Link to Mysql Table](http://bit.ly/IItzkT)

I'm trying to have a basic website display info from a table to use as content. I run this

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT cont_id, cont_text FROM content") or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($conn));   
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

Each page_location is a page on the website. I would like to do something like

```
<?php echo $row['cont_text'] WHERE cont_id = 15; ?>
```

I know that's not right but then down the page I would echo cont_text from a new cont_id. How would I go about this?

Do I need to reorganize my table? Or multiple mysqli_query's?

Comment: Can you not achieve what you're asking by doing `<?php if((int)$row['cont_id'] == 15) echo $row['cont_text']; ?>`?

Comment: Ya, vinodadhikary, something like that. Tried your code, got no return, no error. Just white space.

Comment: try echoing `$row['cont_id']` or `var_dump($row)` to verify that you are getting correct result from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>You're over-thinking it. Just run one query using `cont_id` in the where clause of the query:</s>

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT cont_text FROM content WHERE cont_id = 15") or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($conn)); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['cont_text'];
```

**edit**

Based on your comments try this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT cont_id , cont_text FROM content") or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($conn)); 
$content = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $content[$row['cont_id']] = $row['cont_text'];
}
echo $content[15];
```

Comment: I would do that but I need to do this for over about 10+ items per page. So from there would I just run the query again for the next cont_text on the page?

Comment: John Conde, I've been working on this for days and that did the trick! Was thinking an array but wasn't sure.